# Google Analytics Reporting API V.4.0. returning different number of rows for certain date depending on date range

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

I really hope someone can explain this for me.

I have set up a script that makes requests to the [Google Analytics Reporting API V.4.0.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) using Python to fetch session data. However, depending on what date range I use, some dates return different number of rows.

For example, when requesting data for (in this case) 2018-05-17, I get 41 rows. The number of rows for that day stay at 41 if I extend the date range slightly, but if I go too far, say from 2018-05-01 to 2018-07-10, then the number of rows for 2018-05-17 suddenly change from 41 to 40. One row is missing and I get no clue that it happens, and certainly not to why it happens.

I don't get any indication that the data is sampled (`samplesReadCounts` and `samplesReadCounts` are both undefined). I have also taken care of pagination by making consecutive requests with `pageToken` set to the previous `nextPageToken` value (unless `pageSize` is high enough, as it is in the request below). I also get the correct number of rows for all other dates in the date range (compared to the number of rows returned with the date range set to each single date).

This is the body I use for this specific request (dummy `viewId`):

```
{'reportRequests': [{'viewId': '123456789',
   'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-05-01', 'endDate': '2018-07-10'}],
   'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'},
    {'name': 'ga:sourceMedium'},
    {'name': 'ga:campaign'},
    {'name': 'ga:deviceCategory'}],
   'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
    {'expression': 'ga:pageviews'},
    {'expression': 'ga:bounces'},
    {'expression': 'ga:sessionDuration'},
    {'expression': 'ga:newUsers'}],
   'pageToken': '0',
   'pageSize': '10000',
   'includeEmptyRows': True,
   'hideTotals': True,
   'hideValueRanges': True}]}
```

And this is the response with all rows stripped:

```
{'columnHeader': {'dimensions': ['ga:date',
   'ga:sourceMedium',
   'ga:campaign',
   'ga:deviceCategory'],
  'metricHeader': {'metricHeaderEntries': [{'name': 'ga:sessions',
     'type': 'INTEGER'},
    {'name': 'ga:pageviews', 'type': 'INTEGER'},
    {'name': 'ga:bounces', 'type': 'INTEGER'},
    {'name': 'ga:sessionDuration', 'type': 'TIME'},
    {'name': 'ga:newUsers', 'type': 'INTEGER'}]}},
 'data': {'rows': [], 'rowCount': 3817, 'isDataGolden': True}}
```

I can see no indication that the data should not be complete and correct. But still, one row is missing.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same issue in the UI as well? Try to create a custom report with same dimensions and metrics and see if changing the date range changes the values returned matching the API.

Comment: @Eduardo, I have tried three different UI now; [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), [Try this API in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) and [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet). All are giving the same result. One row (always the same row, by the way) is missing.

Comment: What about in the UI, using a custom Report? The normal GA interface

Comment: @Eduardo, the normal GA interface reproduces the error and the exact same row is still missing.